# Converting service fabric actors to kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, azure-service-fabric, actor

I'm investigating converting my service fabric application to kubernetes. One area I'm struggling with, is what the equivalent of service fabric actors is in kubernetes? I mainly use reminder actors in the application, is there an equivalent in kubernetes?

Comment: kubernetes doesnt offer anything like that, but there might be some service that can be created on top of kubernetes that could do something similar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use actor programming model on k8s you should use the combination of actor framework ([orleans](https://dotnet.github.io/orleans/) or [akka.net](https://getakka.net/articles/concepts/actors.html)) and k8s [stateful sets.](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/)

Talk from Oslo NDC 2019 [Real-Time, Distributed Applications with Akka.NET, Kubernetes and .NET Core](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dzI7tfK0p2I)

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [dapr](https://github.com/dapr/dapr) runtime. It is heavily influenced by Microsoft's learning of Service Fabric Reliable Services/Actors and runs on top of Kubernetes (and others).

Take into account that it is still in development and not yet released for production scenarios.

Comment: .Net SDK for Dapr Actors: https://github.com/dapr/dotnet-sdk/blob/master/docs/get-started-dapr-actor.md